# What is wrong with this .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

In my root directory are two subfolders production and development. I would like to send all incoming traffic to the production folder, thats where my site is.

In the root i have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    production/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) production/$1    [L]
```

When i browse to the domain name I keep getting an internal server error.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /poduction/
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still get an internal server error. But that should really be impossible right?